# Borland Builder 2006 DLL used in C# .Net - System.StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, c++builder, dllimport

I have a old DLL (Borland Builder 2006 C++) which I want to use in .Net C# Visual Studio 2010. When I try to import the functions in VS always I get a StackOverflowException from Visual Studio. I've already read a lot stuff and the import seems to be easy. But I fail and don't see my error.

**In the Borland DLL the Functions are exported as:**

- `__declspec(dllexport) void TestFunc1()`  or
- `extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall TestFunc2()`

**The decorated names are (*.DEF file created with impdef and proved with dependency walker):**

- `@TestFunc1$qqsv`
- `TestFunc2`

In Visual Studio I import in this way:

```
[DllImport("MyDllName.dll", EntryPoint = "@TestFunc1$qqsv", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void TestFunc1();

[DllImport("MyDllName.dll",CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern void TestFunc2();
```

In booth cases a get a StackOverflowException from Visual studio, when I call:

- `MyImport_Unmanaged.TestFunc1()` or
- `MyImport_Unmanaged.TestFunc2()`

What is wrong ? Can anybody help me ?

Interesting when I import a old dll created with Visual Studio C++ the decorated name of the function is: `_TestFunc1@0`. The name is quite different to the Borland names but is works.

Comment: `SetLastError` is for Win32 API functions. Remove that. `CharSet` is pointless because there are no strings in the parameters. Remove that too. Decoration varies between compilers. Don't be surprised when they differ. `TestFunc1` is not declared as `stdcall`. You should export it as such. It's probably the Borland `register` calling convention. Don't see why `TestFunc2` fails.

Comment: @David: Why remove `SetLastError=true`?

Comment: @abatishchev The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.setlasterror.aspx) say that it "Indicates whether the callee calls the SetLastError Win32 API function before returning from the attributed method." Win32 API functions do that. These functions won't.

Comment: @David: Thanks. thought it has another meaning.

Comment: I can't see any reason why either of these should fail because the various issues I have identified should be benign. Of course you should still fix them. Can you call these DLL functions from a native C++ executable?

Comment: No I removed SetLastError and Charset. Booth functions fail again.

Comment: Addional Info: The Dll ist a 32-Bit version. I use Win7-64Bit. But the C# project is a x86 project. I can use the borland dll in a visual studio C++ console application.

Comment: @user1164592 Well, I already said that `SetLastError` and `Charset` were benign issues. Did you try making `TestFunc1` a `__stdcall` in the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

the correct syntax is:
extern "C" void **__stdcall** __declspec(dllexport) TestFunc1()

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After a lot of experiments I realized that the problem was not a syntax one. It was the fact that the C++ Builder DLL was using VCL Forms. I removed the forms and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Panos seems to be right. I tried to P/Invoke an old BCB5 DLL with VCL and at the
first look it worked quite OK. But it silently has corrupted the C# program which manifests in strange exceptions a little bit later.
Not using the VCL in the Borland DLL was the only way to get it work. For us this means we have to convert our code to VisualStuidio which is on out todo-list anyway.